# Whenever a call a function in selenium, it opens a new window and my program stucks

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

Whenever I call a function in selenium, it opens a new window and my program stucks,
Everything is working fine but whenever compiler comes to the function,then new window opens and if that is supposed to be happening.

Then please suggest any solution so that i can use the same function in the same window because i cant give address again from the start in the newly opened window.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    //Whenever compiler comes to this point, it displays an error
    function1(0,0,100);
    function1(0,1,100);
    function1(0,2,100);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")).click();
    System.out.println("Test case executed successfully");
}
public static void function1(int x, int y, int z) throws InterruptedException{ 
    //Select field drop-down
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    Select oSelect=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")));       
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String S2=String.valueOf(x);
    oSelect.selectByValue(S2);
    //Select Operator drop-down
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Select oSelect2=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(" xpath_address")));     
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String S3=String.valueOf(y);
    oSelect2.selectByValue(S3);
    // Provide input to value
    String S=String.valueOf(z);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")).sendKeys(S);
    //Click on input Filters
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")).click();

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();`. Every time you create new `FirefoxDriver` instance a new window is being opened. Pass it to `Main` and send it as parameter to `function1`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    function1(driver, 0, 0, 100);
    function1(driver, 0, 1, 100);
    function1(driver, 0, 2, 100);
}

public static void function1(WebDriver driver, int x, int y, int z) throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")).sendKeys(S);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove this `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();` in the function.
2. `private static WebDriver driver`;  declare outside main
3. `driver=new FirefoxDriver();`  - just use this inside the main

   ```
    private static WebDriver driver;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       driver=new FirefoxDriver();
       //Whenever compiler comes to this point, it displays an error
       function1(0,0,100);
       function1(0,1,100);
       function1(0,2,100);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")).click();
       System.out.println("Test case executed successfully");
    }

    public static void function1(int x, int y, int z) throws InterruptedException{ 
       //Select field drop-down
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       //WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
       Select oSelect=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")));       
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       String S2=String.valueOf(x);
       oSelect.selectByValue(S2);
       //Select Operator drop-down
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       Select oSelect2=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(" xpath_address")));     
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       String S3=String.valueOf(y);
       oSelect2.selectByValue(S3);
       // Provide input to value
       String S=String.valueOf(z);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")).sendKeys(S);
       //Click on input Filters
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_address")).click();

                         }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change logic slightly.. First create static webdriver at global level in class. After class {

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

in main method initiate the driver, like below

```
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

in all other functions in that class, use this driver instance only means dont create another driver object. please remove below statement in you functions

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

In this way, you are using only one driver instance no more new browsers will be opened in each new function

Thank You,
Murali G